# Simple Layout Issue on Resize

Tags: html, css

All throughout a page I'm working on I continue to get a repetitive layout error that stems from an attempt to float elements left and right in congruence with one another. However, on re-sized and small browsers the float:right elements collapses under the float:left elements each time.

http://jsfiddle.net/g4dbr3ho/4

```
    #wrap {
        width: 100%;
        height: 100%;
    }

#main {
    float:left;
    max-width: 70%;
    max-height: 100%;
    margin-left:112px;
    padding: 20px;
}
#side {
    float:right;
    width:auto;
    max-height:100%;
    background-color:black;
    border-style:solid;
    border-width:2px;
    border-color:red;
}
```

What I'm looking for is to understand what method is best to use to try executing this format. I'm aware of the inline:block strategy in formatting too, but I find that inaffective in my situation here, also creating new issues.

Comment: what do u wanna achieve? or what u wanna understand? not able to get u clearly!

Comment: I'm completely open to all opinions, I mainly want to understand what is the best thing to do to avoid having the float:right element collapse under the float:left element.

Answer (score 0):

You should create a div around the #main text. Float that one to the left, give it a width and your sidebar to.

```
*{
    box-sizing: border-box;
}
```

I've added box-sizing to all. It includes borders and paddings to the width and height.

http://jsfiddle.net/qmd9shu0/1/

Answer (score 0):

You can use

1. Inline-block ([css display property](http://css-tricks.com/almanac/properties/d/display/)) (with proper width and media queries for responsive if required)
2. [Table-layout](http://css-tricks.com/complete-guide-table-element/) (widely supported)
3. [Flexbox](http://css-tricks.com/snippets/css/a-guide-to-flexbox/) (good to use if >ie8 support required)

Answer (score 0):

First at all, is it nessessary to put the sidemain-div inside the main-div ? If not, put both of them as a direct child of the wrapper. With this, you're able to style these elements by position attributes.

Like this:

```
#wrap {
    width: 100%;
    height: 100%;
}

#main {
    position: absolute;
}

#sidemain {
    position: absolute;
    right: 0;
    margin-left: 10px;
}
```

Comment: Actually this is what I have done, unfortunately I made the mistake in jsfiddle and put them together. The sidemain-div is not wrapped inside of the #main. it's independent. I have tried using position:absolute before on both divs, but it somehow put #sidemain on the left side of the page even though it was under float:right command.

Comment: I tried your approach in full, removing the floats and it's the most improvement I've had to this issue before. The only remaining problem is that I use width:auto on the sidemain-div and it's not resizing when I resize my browser, whereas the main-div resizes properly. I can probably work on correcting that, but if you can suggest a way to correct that, I appreciate it.

Comment: It depends on the content within your sidemain-div. If there is only text, try to set "word-wrap: break-word;". This will force a break after the "margin-left"-attribute is reached. With your jsFiddle example a "margin-left: 50%" seems to be a good result.